# How can I use pasty to create a dmatrix without having to write out each of the variable names individually?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

Say I have a large dataframe, and some lists of columns, and I want to be able to put them in a patsy dmatricies without having to write out each name individually.  That is, I want to call the names from a list a list of column names to form the terms. Rather than write out each and every single term in my data frame column.

For example take the following df

```
    df=pd.DataFrame( {'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8],
                      'c':[8,4,5,3],  'd':[1,3,55,3],
                      'e':[8,4,5,3]})
   df
   >>
        a   b   c   d   e
   0    1   5   8   1   8
   1    2   6   4   3   4
   2    3   7   5   55  5
   3    4   8   3   3   3
```

As I understand it to call this into a d matrix requires me to  do the following:

`y,x = dmatrices('a~b+c+d+e', data=df)`
However I would like to be able to run something more along the lines of:

```
   regress=['b', 'c']
   control=['e', 'd']
   y,x=dmatricies('a~{}+{}'.format(' '.join(e for e in regressors), 
   ' '.join(c for c in control)), data=df)
```

However this was unsuccesful.

I also attempted to use a dictionary with two entries, say regress and control, that filled with lists of the column names, and then input that into the first entry of dmatricies but it didnt work either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a more efficient way to get things into patsy's dmatricies rather than writing out each and every column name we would like to include in the matrix?

Thanks in advance and let me know if I was not clear on anything.

Answer (score 2):

Doing with for loop here

```
for z in regress:
    for t in control:
        y,x=dmatrices('a~{}+{}'.format(z,t), data=df)
        print('a~{}+{}'.format(z,t))
        print(y,x)

a~b+e
[[1.]
 [2.]
 [3.]
 [4.]] [[1. 5. 8.]
 [1. 6. 4.]
 [1. 7. 5.]
 [1. 8. 3.]]
a~c+e
[[1.]
 [2.]
 [3.]
 [4.]] [[1. 8. 8.]
 [1. 4. 4.]
 [1. 5. 5.]
 [1. 3. 3.]]
a~d+e
[[1.]
 [2.]
 [3.]
 [4.]] [[ 1.  1.  8.]
 [ 1.  3.  4.]
 [ 1. 55.  5.]
 [ 1.  3.  3.]]
```

Comment: I had tried a similar thing with list comprehension and it did not work.  `y,x=dmatricies('a~{}+{}.format([x for x in regress], [y for y in controls]), data=df)

Comment: @VictorNogueira that is determined by whether `dmatricies` accept multiple input within in one times

Comment: Running the following where x_regress and controls are two lists:          `for z in controls: for x in x_regress: y,j=dmatrices('perf~{}+{}'.format(z,x), data=df)` I through the following error: `Categorical data cannot be > 1D`.  I am using geneder however as a control (coded 0/1). When I enter it manually it works.

Comment: @VictorNogueira what is perf ?

Comment: My Apologies, that is my dependent variable in my actual problem. So im trying to regress performance against a variety of traits and characteristics. Moreover, im trying to do so in different sets (e.g. i have 6 sets of ~60 independent variables each) which is why i'm really trying to find a way to loop over this. perf is a single vector of performance ratings.

Comment: Essentially in my real problem I have the following 6 different dataframes of the regressors, and controls, and each of those data frames maps to the same y -- performance.  However each of these 6 data frames has different independent variables. Does it make sense?

Comment: @VictorNogueira try with me code with your sample data , if that work , then you just need to convert your data into that format

Comment: I did. I converted the column names to a list of strings via x_regressors = df.columns.tolist() I inputted the y variable as a single 'perf' variable because it is only one column.  Moreover I entered my two controls. SO here is what I ran in the loop       `for x in x_regress:
    y,t = dmatrices('perf~{}+age+sex'.format(x), data=df)`

Comment: @VictorNogueira I have show my output base on your sample input , if this is not what you need , then you question can not address your problem

Comment: The question is formatted correctly, are you familiar with patsy? I'm not sure you understand what the discrepancy here is.  I will look more into this on Monday.